# Maven Filtering parameters in file

Tags: java, maven

I have been looking over the maven war plugin and how to configure it. Here is my situation. I have a web application that is distributed to several production facilities. There are two files, in this web app, that are customized for each facility. These are /js/config.js and /META-INF/context.xml.

I have my project in a typical maven structure:

```
/src
|--/main
   |--webapp
      |--/js
         |--config.js
         |--properties
            |--plant.properties
      |--/META-INF
         |--context.xml
```

I've left out non-essential directories for brevity.

The config.js has been altered to contain "parameter" I want substituted:

```
var Config {
    ...
    system_title: '${plant_name} - Audit System',
    ...
}
```

The relevant portion of my pom is:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                src/main/webapp/js/properties/fayetteville.properties
            </filters>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/js</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <exclude>**/properties</exclude>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When I run "mvn clean package", I would expect to see ${plant_name} replaced with what is in my properties file. In this case, my properties file contains a single key-value pair:

```
plant_name=Austin
```

But I am not seeing the substitution. The resulting config.js in the target folder still contains ${plant_name} as does the config.js in the resulting war file.

I really don't want to use profiles if possible. Eventually, I want the build process to use a list of properties files to do this for all plants.

From my research, including a number of SO questions and answers, I feel I have things configured correctly.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: You don't use the same syntax than in the documentation. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html `webResource` is not referenced but  `resource`. Where did you find this syntax ?

Comment: @davidxxx, thank you for pointing that out. I made the correction in my pom and edited the question. Still the same result, unfortunately